# Detecting texture in image

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, textures

I have an aerial photo that contains trees and roofs of houses, and I need to detect only the trees. To do that I thought about using an algorithm that detect texture (maybe OpenCV or other) but I dont know how to implement it.

Image:
[image]

OpenCV is the best in this case? Do you know another algorithm that do what I want? How can I implement it?

Comment: Do you **have** to use texture?  The trees have a unique hue in comparison to the rest of the background.  Could you simply detect that colour instead?

Comment: I can use anything that separate the trees from the roofs. The texture it's only an suggestion

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345311/detect-plants-in-a-grass-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Hue channel of the above image looks like : [image]

Then you can threshold this image using a hard-coded value or you can use Otsu's method to find the threshold.

To do all this use, you can use OpenCV APIs.